# How to copy one exe file to client and run this file with server?

Tags: windows, client, exe

How to copy one exe file to client and run this file with server?

I have a large network and i want to run one exe file in totall client.

How can help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553):

> PsExec is a light-weight telnet-replacement that lets you execute processes on other systems, complete with full interactivity for console applications, without having to manually install client software.

You can execute `psexec <remotehost> -c <path\to\executable\on\local\host>`

Comment: How do i use this application for my problem?

Comment: I have a large network and i can'nt install PsExec client applicatopn in totall client. Please help me.

Comment: I am not shure if there should be an easy way to do this because of security issues. Something has to be done on every client you want to "update". otherwhise you would make many hackers happy.

Comment: From the link: "PsExec is a light-weight telnet-replacement that lets you execute processes on other systems, complete with full interactivity for console applications, without having to manually install client software."

Comment: I'm a noob, apparently edits can't be multi-line. Again, the usage is in the link, but you can execute "psexec <remotehost> -c <path\to\executable\on\local\host>".